# Can same service be launched in 2 different namespaces with type nodeport on the same port?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster set up in a private cloud. Idea is all the developers would be using this cluster to launch all the microservices needed for the app. Each developer would launch all the deployments/services in his namespace to avoid collision. Since this cloud doesn't support LoadBalancer , I have used nodePort with a port defined to expose external IP for the front end. And I access the front end using

http://node-ip:port

However Since K8s can launch any number of front-end pods of different namespaces on the same node -I will have a collision because that nodePort is already assigned to the service launched first. I now cant understand on how can I allow multiple people using same services to launch in the same cluster.

Sample Service Config is below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8884
    targetPort: 8081
    nodePort: 30080
    name: ui
  selector:
    app: test
  type: NodePort
```

This frontend service can be accessed by http://node-ip:30080 if run for the first time. What happens if we run the same yaml across different namespace in the same node? How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define nodePort at all, it is then automaticaly assigned to the Service by kubernetes and henceforth it avoids any collisions whatsoever.

Comment: I am aware that if we do not give node ports , it would pick an available port. But the current requirement is that some microservices expect a few services to be available externally on a certain port only always. Hence the hardcoded NodePort value.

Comment: Then NodePort is not enough for you. What you need is support for LoadBalancer type of service. It builds up upon NodePort, so you will get random node ports but it also sets up the LoadBalancer provided in the infrastructure to forward from your chosen Port to that NodePort. Meaning you end up with multiple IPs and the same ports.